Configure SSHD via Red Hat crypto-policy
I am using Rocky Linux 8 and 9 and they use the crypto-policy framework from Red Hat.  Now I want to adjust some settings in the policy to forbid sshd to use some specific algorithms.  But I can not figure out the names for these algorithms as they should be given to crypro-policy (I only know the names as openssh accepts them).
I am writing a text file at /etc/crypto-policies/policies/modules/DEPRECATED-SSH-ALGOS.pmod and try to set my policy to DEFAULT:DEPRECATED-SSH-ALGOS in /etc/crypto-policies/config.
The problem is the content of the DEPRECATED-SSH-ALGOS.pmod file. Some algorithms I can successfully deactivate and others I can't. In some cases I can easily guess the name that crypto-policy uses from the name that ssh uses.
"Working" version of the file:
cipher@ssh = -AES-*-CBC
mac@SSH = -*-SHA1 -HMAC-SHA2-256 -HMAC-SHA2-512

but I would like to use something like this:
cipher@ssh = -AES-*-CBC
mac@SSH = -*-SHA1 -HMAC-SHA2-256 -HMAC-SHA2-512 -UMAC-128@OPENSSH.COM
key_exchange@SSH = -*-SHA1 -ECDH-SHA2-NISTP256 -ECDH-SHA2-NISTP384 -ECDH-SHA2-NISTP521

but the crypto-policy framework complains that it does not know this algorithm, when I update-crypto-policies --set:
AlgorithmEmptyMatchError: Bad value of policy property `key_exchange`: `ecdh-sha2-nistp256`
Errors found in policy, first one:
Bad value of policy property `key_exchange`: `ECDH-SHA2-NISTP256`

Question
What are the names of the algorithms I can put in a crypto-policy file or where do I find these?
Or: Given a ssh specific algorithm name, how can I figure out the crypto-policy name for that algorithm?

EDIT
I have since found the file /usr/share/crypto-policies/python/policygenerators/openssh.py on my Rocky machine which seems to map these names:
# ...
kx_map = {
        'ECDHE-SECP521R1-SHA2-512':'ecdh-sha2-nistp521',
        'ECDHE-SECP384R1-SHA2-384':'ecdh-sha2-nistp384',
        'ECDHE-SECP256R1-SHA2-256':'ecdh-sha2-nistp256',
# ...
}
#...

The problem is that some of the names there did not work as well. Either of
key_exchange@SSH = -ecdh-sha2-nistp256
# or
key_exchange@SSH = -ECDHE-SECP256R1-SHA2-256

results in Bad value of policy property `key_exchange`  when I update-crypto-policies --set.

/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config
check out:   https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_8/2021-12-03/finding/V-230251

RHEL 8 incorporates system-wide crypto policies by default. The SSH configuration file has no effect on the ciphers, MACs, or algorithms unless specifically defined in the /etc/sysconfig/sshd file. The employed algorithms can be viewed in the /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config file.
Configure the RHEL 8 SSH server to use only MACs employing FIPS 140-2-approved algorithms by updating the "/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config" file with the following line:


-oMACS=hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com


A reboot is required for the changes to take effect.

V-230252 : CRYPTO_POLICY='-oCiphers=aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com'
V-255924 : -oKexAlgorithms=ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
also look at V230254 for openssl, note - take all this as a guideline.
also :
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/using-the-system-wide-cryptographic-policies_security-hardening

For defining custom cryptographic policies, see the Custom Policies section in the update-crypto-policies(8) man page and the Crypto Policy Definition Format section in the crypto-policies(7) man page

man crypto-policies 7   ... CRYPTO POLICY DEFINITON FORMAT

Sadly this does not answer the question. The files in /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends are generated by update-crypto-policies --set (see man update-crypto-policies, section FILES). I do not want to edit generated files but I want to edit the policy modification file (/etc/crypto-policies/policies/modules/DEPRECATED-SSH-ALGOS.pmod) that instructs update-crypto-policies how to generate the files in /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends. I have read both man pages you link but found no hint how to name the algorithms I am looking for in the pmod file.

I am not sure what you are actually asking then, the syntax of the algorithms can be found from that -oKexAlgorithms= list, and how you are able to mess with that syntax was in that redhat article link.  There is also https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/using-the-system-wide-cryptographic-policies_security-hardening  stating you can find subpolicy examples at /usr/share/crypto-policies/policies/

I have not gone so far as to write .pol or .pmod files, check out any of the .pmod files under /usr/share/crypto-policies/policies/modules... NO-CAMELLIA.pmod for example has example policy dropping the Camellia support altogether having cipher = -CAMELLIA-*.  you would model your file after any of the examples using the correct syntax of those algorithms listed in opensshserver.config after oKexAlgorithms=.

system wide crypto policy disable CBC for SSH .pmod example : https://www.tenable.com/audits/items/CIS_Red_Hat_EL8_Workstation_v3.0.0_L1.audit:16627f485589d06e282cc96fab1d8651

My problem is that sshd and crypto-policy use different names for the same algorithms. So I have to find the name as crypto-policy accepts it in order to deactivate a specific ssh algorithm. I have since found the file /usr/share/crypto-policies/python/policygenerators/openssh.py which seems to do the mapping. I was able to deactivate some more algos by using the uppercase names from there but some are still not working. Modelling after NO-CAMILLA or similar files does not help as long as they do not list the exact algorithms I am looking for. I will update my question to make it more clear.

you also realize that where u stated want to adjust some settings in the policy to forbid sshd to use some specific algorithms - that simply modifying /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config and taking out what you don't want accomplishes that?   That's why I posted those STIG V-### for reference, for the mac, cipher, and algorithms.  I don't know how you can do any better than that for ssh-server.  Was i missing something?  I don't know why it is worth messing with the pmod stuff like u were describing.
